# Download from one API and upload to Google Drive API

Tags: python, api, woocommerce, google-drive-api

I am attempting to download from one API source and immediately upload directly to Google Drive API. The code I am attaching below details a local download and then local upload, which I would like to avoid, if I can. I can always remove the local file that is temporarily created, but this also I would like to avoid.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

import json
import pandas as pd
from woocommerce import API

gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

wcapi = API(
    url="https://my_website.com",
    consumer_key="my_key",
    consumer_secret="my_secret",
    version="wc/v3"
)

products = wcapi.get("products", params={"per_page": 100, "page": 1}).json()
pd.json_normalize(products)

with open('products.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(products, f)
    f.close()

upload_file = 'products.json'
gfile = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'products.json',
                          'parents': [{'id': 'my_specific_folder'}]})
gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
gfile.Upload()
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The code I am attaching below details a local download and then local upload, which I would like to avoid`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike it should probably say "entails" instead of "details", but that's still a difficult word. The meaning is that OP does not want to have to download the file onto the local storage and upload it again. Instead the file should be sent directly from one web API to another, perhaps holding the file in memory.

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I apologize for my poor English skill. And, for example, is this sample script close to the expected result? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64565436

Comment: @Tanaike
Thank you for reposting your link to the proposed solution. I can not revisit this proposed solution until the end of this week, but when I do, I will let you know if it is successful.